# Configure a custom password reset policy with a read-only Email field in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

How to convert or manipulate a regular email field that accepts user email id for verification to a readonlyEmail field that prepopulates a user email id when performing a password reset.

I have configured a custom password reset policy that passes in an id_token_hint and login_hint to the read-only claim which populates the read-only Email field with users email id. However, 2 email fields are seen, the first which is the rea-donly Email field and the second is the regular email field that accepts user email id.

I commented out the email claim in the LocalAccountReadPasswordUsingObjectId of the trustframeworkbase policy. This removed the second email field, but I was unable to perform the password reset as I believe the email field is required for password reset.

Is it possible to manipulate the email field to a read-only Email for the password reset? If so. How could I achieve a password reset policy with read-only Email without having two email fields?

[readonlyEmail claim type][1]

[Claim transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZnRX.png)

[Technical profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9D4c.png)

Run Now Output

[Password reset flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8uf9.png)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8sMQ.png

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your **CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId** technical profile reading the email address from the token as **email**.

create a claim type as follows:

```
  <ClaimType Id="userId">
    <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
  </ClaimType>
```

Add a claim transformation:

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
        <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}"/>
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userId" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
    </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Change your **LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress** technical profile as follows:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress">
      <DisplayName>Reset password using email address</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountpasswordreset</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateReadonlyEmailClaim" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userId"/>
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userId" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />

      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

All done!

**Note:** Make necessary changes to the above pieces to match your custom policy.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the response.
I have edited the post with my screenshots.
I believe I have done the recommended steps but still have same result.
Any further suggestions?

Comment: Everything looking good, but not sure how the two email inputs coming over there. Please try to upload and rewrite all policies (from base to relying party) and run it again from the azure portal itself (if you are not did before). Not related your issue, if you are using the default validation TP <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress" />, then it is expecting email claimtype, please consider that too. If you are using a custom UI, please ensure that no input control for email is placed in HTML.

Comment: @NathanOhere issue resolved? I tried the same before posting this answer, for me it shown only one control for email address.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Alex. I haven't redone it yet from scratch. But just to confirm is the email field you get readOnly?

Comment: Yes, email was readonly